# Constraint for each element in an array to be repeated exactly 5 times is not working

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I want to randomize an array of 50 elements in such a way that it has 10 different numbers between 1 to 20, each occurring exactly 5 times. I have written the below code which is not working. Could anyone please point out the issue?

```
module top;

class A;
rand bit [5:0] num[50];

constraint c1 { 
   foreach (num[i]) num[i] inside {[1:20]};}
      
constraint c2 { 
   foreach (num[i]) num.sum() with (int'(item==num[i]))==5; }
        
endclass

A a=new;
initial begin
    a.randomize();
    $display("%p", a.num);
end
endmodule
```

For some reason, if I change:

```
foreach (num[i]) num.sum()
  with (int'(item==num[i]))==5;
```

to:

```
foreach (num[i]) num.sum()
  with (int'(item==num[i])) < 5;
```

it works but doesnt work for exact 5 values.

Comment: Is it that you want 10 randomly selected values in the range 1-20, each appearing 5 times? And should the array be in random order? If so, create an array of size 20 with values 1-20, randomise it, take the first 5 elements and copy them each 5 times into your size 50 array, then randomise that.

Answer (score 2):

When I run your code, the simulation seems to hang on 2 different simulators.  I don't know why because I don't understand the syntax you used in `c2`.

I'll use syntax that is more straightforward.  One way is to use a helper array to create 10 unique random values that are then added to the array of 50 numbers, 5 times each.

```
module tb;

class A;
         bit [5:0] num  [50];
    rand bit [5:0] temp [10];

    // This constraint produces 10 unique numbers between 1 and 20
    constraint c1 { 
        foreach (temp[i]) temp[i] inside {[1:20]};
        unique {temp};
    }

    // This fills the 50-element array with 5 sets of the 
    // 10 unique numbers, then randomizes the order with shuffle
    function void post_randomize;
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
                num[10*i+j] = temp[j];
        num.shuffle();
    endfunction
endclass

A a = new();
initial begin
    if (!a.randomize()) $finish;;
    $display("%p", a.num);
end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
'{'h5, 'h11, 'h7, 'ha, 'h5, 'hc, 'h12, 'hf, 'h12, 'hf, 'h5, 'h11, 'h4, 'h7, 'h4, 'h9, 'ha, 'h12, 'h3, 'h9, 'h7, 'hf, 'hf, 'h4, 'hc, 'h11, 'h5, 'hc, 'h12, 'h3, 'h4, 'h3, 'h3, 'ha, 'h9, 'hf, 'h12, 'h9, 'h7, 'h7, 'hc, 'ha, 'h5, 'h9, 'h11, 'h4, 'hc, 'h11, 'ha, 'h3}
```

Comment: The reason it hangs on EDAPlayground is the constraints are too complex for the time limits imposed. Using `num[15]` gives you correct results.